# Docker Theme Jupyter

Tags: css, docker, jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter

I recently installed the data science notebook for Jupyter but i cant seem to install any themes on it.

Using the local version i have installed a dark theme and i am used to it.

Following this [guide and the install section](https://github.com/powerpak/jupyter-dark-theme) I tried making /custom/ folder and added a cascading style sheet  into the mounted volume. But it doesn't seem to work.

Is there anyway i can install a custom theme on the docker image?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is: add the custom.css file locally under '~/.jupyter/custom/'. When the docker container runs, it will automatically adopt the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually install `jupyter-themes` and opt for a theme on Dockerfile itself. Here is a example for reference

1. Install jupyter-themes using pip

```
RUN pip3 install jupyterthemes
```

2. Opt for a theme

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "jt -t solarizedd -T -N && jupyter notebook --port=8888 --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --notebook-dir=/home/user/workdir"]
```

Here is a complete docker file sample for reference

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install Python and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    wget

# Install Jupyter
RUN pip3 install jupyter
RUN pip3 install jupyterthemes

# Create a user with a home directory
RUN useradd --create-home --home-dir /home/user user
USER user

# Mount a volume for the working directory
VOLUME /home/user/workdir

# Set the default command to launch Jupyter
CMD ["bash", "-c", "jt -t solarizedd -T -N && jupyter notebook --port=8888 --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --notebook-dir=/home/user/workdir"]
# CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--notebook-dir=/home/user/workdir"]
```

You can also include the said command on a docker-compose file, if you are using a docker image

```
version: "3"
services:
  notebook:
    image: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user/workdir
    command: bash -c "pip install jupyterthemes && jt -t solarizedd -T -N"
```

Here i have chosen the `solarizedd` theme, just tweak and include the theme that best suits for you.

Hope this helps